# Handling a Linq-To-Sql mapping to a table colum with a default value/binding

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a Linq-To-SQL mapping to a column in a SQL table.

This column is type DateTime with default mapping / binding of getdate().

The problem is that Linq-To-SQL tries to insert 12/1/0001 12:00 AM instead of letting SQL do its thing and insert getdate().

Is there a way around this?

Additionally, if the column is allowed to be null, why does 'Linq-to-SQL' try to insert a default value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386929.aspx#sectionToggle8) might help (scroll up a wee little bit). It talks of setting the [IsDbGenerated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.isdbgenerated.aspx) and [AutoSync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.autosync.aspx) properties, which tell the data context that the value is generated at the DB and how the value in the L2SQL object should be synced with the value in the database.

I think my google fu is low today, I'm positive I've read a good article/blog post about this, but I cannae find it again.

Comment: You'll want to set Auto-Sync to "OnInsert". If you only want to use the default value and never update it through code, set Auto Generated Value to TRUE as well. Details with examples here: http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2009/2/6/using-default-values-in-linq-to-sql.aspx